# How can I know if the polynomial $x^4 -16x^3 +12x^2 - 3x + 9$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

How can I know if the polynomial $x^4 -16x^3 +12x^2 - 3x + 9$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

I have tried to use Eisenstein's criterion by evaluating on polynomials of the form ax+b but I have not been able to get anywhere. I have also tried to use the Gaussian criterion but I can't come up with anything useful either.

Comment: First show it hasn't got an integer root.  Then argue that it can't be the product of two integer quadratics.

Comment: If nothing else helps , apply the Kronecker method (it is however time consuming). Have you tried to find a prime $p$ such that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$ ? It turns out that already $p=2$ does the job.

Comment: @lulu I imagine I could do what you say by contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

The polynomial is obviously irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$ (or $\Bbb F_5$). By the residue criterion, it is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$.

Edit: by "obviously" I mean, that it has no root in $\Bbb F_2$, and that a comparison of coefficients in
$$
x^4-x+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)
$$
gives equations, which obviously have no solution in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: How is it obvious?  (For the case of $\mathbb{F}_2$, my argument would be: if it had linear or quadratic factors, then the roots of such a factor would be in $\mathbb{F}_4$.  But every element of $\mathbb{F}_4$ satisfies $x^4 = x$, which implies that $p(x) = x^4 - x + 1 = 1$, giving a contradiction.  But that argument is far from obvious.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think you agree that it has no linear factor over $\Bbb F_2$. So we must have $x^4-x+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$, and now solving equations over $\Bbb Z/2$ is really obvious.